# How can I tell varnish to send https to master?

Tags: ssl, nginx, load-balancing, varnish

I have a couple NGINX servers running behind a load balancer.

How can I tell varnish to send all incoming requests on any domain over https to 10.x.x.x:443 (master_ip:443)? We handle lots of sites on a central system so a pattern of some sort would be needed.

Answer (score 3):

Try this redirect as a starting point and customize to your multi-site setup:

```
sub vcl_recv {
    if ( (req.http.host ~ "^(?i)somesite.org" || req.http.host ~ "^(?i)www.somesite.org")
         && req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto !~ "(?i)https") {
        set req.http.x-Redir-Url = "https://www.somesite.org" + req.url;
        error 750 req.http.x-Redir-Url;
    }
}

sub vcl_error {
    if (obj.status == 750) {
        set obj.http.Location = obj.response;
        set obj.status = 302;
        return (deliver);
    }
```

Referenced from [this link](https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/VCLExampleRedirectInVCL):

> Useful when you want to redirect the clients to an SSL-version of your
>   site, given that your varnish instance is running behind some
>   SSL-termination point, such as a nginx instance with SSL enabled.

Comment: Excellent - looks like I can use that second condition after &&. I'll try this when I get home thanks!